# How to iterate java arraylist with javascript or jquery in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, arraylist

I have Arraylist which is comming from controller to jsp. Now I have Arraylist in jsp.

Assume that Arraylist contains 100 records.Now I need to show only 10 records initially.

I am providing the **show more link** in the jsp,when user click on the link,I need to show

another 10 records should be append to previous one.

Here I don't want to use any ajax call, why because I already whole List in jsp.

I want to use js or jquery for this requirement.

Please provide me any suggestions,how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand what is on server side and what is on client side. The array list that you have is on server side in the servlet. Remember that All jsp's gets compiled to servlets.

You can use javascript or jQuery on client side only.

Now there are two scenarios how you implement your pagination.

Approach 1. Get all the records and than use jQuery etc to navigate the pages. There will be no server call.

Approach 2) Every time user hits show more you make server call and get the records and display.

which approach you choose depends on your application.

Comment: Thank you , I am not in confusion.I have java array List ,I want to iterate it in jsp with js or jquery.

Comment: If you need some javascript processing on server side you can check node.js. But I am not sure how that fits in this scenario.

Comment: Here I already have total records in the jsp with java array list, I dont want to make any call every time when I am clicking on show more link.Just need to iterate in the jsp every time clicking on the link.Here I want to follow **Approach 1. Get all the records and than use jquery etc to navigate the pages. There will be no server call.**

Comment: There are various ways to do it. One simplest may not be the most efficient is you can keep the results in session. and when you hit show more access the results stored in session and return next 10 records etc.

Comment: Thanks,can you share any code or link regarding this,it will helpful for me.

Comment: But keep in mind for Approach 1, if your result set is thousands of records or more that may not be the best solution.

Comment: See if this helps you http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/ or look at this other link very close to what you are looking for. http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/ultimate-paging-practice-through-jquery-ajax/